# DocuSign API Returns Un Authorized Client

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am getting 400 bad request with DocuSign demo account while accessing access token. I am using these values while making call.

$url = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token";

$integrator_and_secret_key = "Basic " . base64_encode("integration key:secret key");

```
        $headers = [
            "Authorization" => $integrator_and_secret_key,
            "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ];
        
        $postData = [
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "code"       => $_GET['code'],
        ];
        
    
        $curl = curl_init($url);
                                    
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=authorization_code&code=authcode");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers 
        );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);      
        $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        
        if ( $status != 201 ) {
            echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
            print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
            exit(-1);
        }
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($json_response); exit;
        $response = json_decode($json_response, true);      
        // if(isset($response["envelopeId"])){
            // echo json_encode(array('output'=>'success'));
        // }
        // else{
            // echo json_encode(array('status'=>False,'output'=>'Fail'));exit;
        // }
                                    
        exit;
```

There was an error calling "web service" after I called above, status: 400 error text -> error "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "unauthorized_client"} "

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and include the full (!) output it produces including the response headers. In any case, the meaning of a 400 is pretty well defined, please make sure you understand it. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to use the oauth authorization code grant flow.

The code that your q shows is the second major step where your app exchanges the authorization code it received from DocuSign for an access token that will be used to call the API.

Your code appears to be using the static string `authcode` as the authorization code:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    "grant_type=authorization_code&code=authcode");
```

This is a bug. The `code` body parameter must be set to the value of the authorization code that was previously received from DocuSign.

Eg

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    "grant_type=authorization_code&code=$authcode");
```

### Recommendation

Instead of hand-coding the authorization code grant, it is better to use a library. For PHP, the open source `league/oauth2-client` can be used. [Docs](http://oauth2-client.thephpleague.com)

The DocuSign code example shows how to use it. See the [Auth directory](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/tree/master/src/Controllers/Auth) and its callers.